# OpenAPI specs generated with Swashbuckle contains default empty value for each parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, openapi, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm using Swashbuckle (5.0.0-rc2, I know there is newer versions but I do not have the control on that point) for multiple ASP.NET Core projects.

For all projects (except one) everything is working fine, the specs generated are OK and the "default" value for "in" parameters only appear when I explicitly put it into the code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<object[]>> Search(string searchString, [FromQuery] int pageNumber = 1, [FromQuery] int pageSize = 10)
```

So the specs will look like:

```
  {
    "name": "searchString",
    "in": "query",
    "schema": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "pageNumber",
    "in": "query",
        "schema": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32",
          "default": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "pageSize",
        "in": "query",
        "schema": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32",
          "default": 10
        }
      }
```

The "default" property is only displayed when it's in the code.

For my other project (so same nuget version and almost same configuration) the behavior is different and I have the "default" property for each parameter but empty. In the code there is no default value:

```
  {
    "name": "startDate",
    "in": "query",
    "required": true,
    "schema": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time",
      "default": ""
    }
```

The issue is when I'm validating the semantic of the specs (which is done when I upload the file to Azure API Manager) it causes some issue: The default value "empty" is of course not valid for a date-time value.

Only difference in swagger configuration is the second project is using a custom way to generated schema ID... But I got the issue with "in" parameter with primitive type so it should not have any influence. Other configurations are exactly the same (we're using an internal nuget package to ensure that).

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the code from your other project where the `startDate` parameter is defined?

Comment: Actually I removed our own nuget to use directly swashbuckle and it seems I don't have the issue anymore... 
So now I'm trying to figure out how it can work properly in other projects... :-)